# Angular integration testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, integration-testing, protractor

I'm not having much luck googling this, so, here goes...

I've got an Angular application, which talks to an node (express) API, and we've got no integration testing - making it too easy to 'break' the integration between the two parts of the system, having to test by hand is obviously far from ideal.

I wanted to avoid Protractor (we've got a really rich UI in the angular app, and it's proving difficult get protractor to play nice). As it stands, we have a fairly standard structure for an angular app - controllers that feed data to views (using 'Controller as'). The controllers interact with services, services do all the $http calls.

Ideally, I'd test from the controllers 'down'. Is there anything out there to support this kind of approach?

The most promising approach appears to be stopping angular-mocks from injecting it's own mocked $http/$httpbackend. But I'm keen to hear your thoughts on this and alternative approaches.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: I have been testing a very large Angular application with Protractor for a long time. The tests are very stable and they provide great signal when we break something. Why wouldn't you use Protractor? Do you have some examples for which it doesn't work?

Comment: @AndresD We've got some rich (html5) parts to our angular application, and we're having trouble getting Protractor to play nice (drag n drop for example, requires some javascript "polyfiller" to simulate drag and drop events) With this in mind, we're not 'really' testing these parts of the application. Better than nothing? Definitely, but maybe there is a better option - testing everything from the "controller as" down?